# How to stop NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a character shooting and I want him to only shoot when user is touching the screen, I keep getting this error "'GameScene' does not have a member named 'stimer'
here is the code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        var stimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnShot"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        player.position.x = location.x

    }
}
   override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent: UIEvent){
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        if self.stimer.valid{

            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that any variable or constant declared inside of a method is only available in that method.

I think that it would solve this problem if you declared `stimer` outside of `touchesBegan` as `var stimer:NSTimer!` and then just pass your arguments like you've done inside of `touchesBegan`. You then probably don't need the `self.` before the name of the timer.

Also, it looks like you're invalidating a different timer than you are checking the validity of? This could be another problem, I don't know if you did this on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your timer in your GameScene `init` method or in any other initial function, like this:

```
var gameLoop:NSTimer?
var hitByEnemy:Bool = false

// you need to implement this method otherwise Xcode will throw an error
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    self.gameLoop = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "gameLoopTimerTicked:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

then you need to create the method that `NSTimer` will call when a certain time interval elapsed:

```
func gameLoopTimerTicked(timer:NSTimer){
    if self.hitByEnemy {

        self.gameLoop?.invalidate()   
    }
}
```

and in another function you should define if your character was hit by enemy or any other event who should stop your timer.